# Yup validation of empty string

Tags: yup

I want to setup a minimal validation of user input. First I want to validate that it is not an empty string so something like

```
yup.string().min(10);
```

I also want to validate that it has a date format, so

```
yup.string().min(10).date();
```

I also want to compare it to another date to make sure the range makes sense.

I have looked at the yup documentation and cannot understand how to accomplish these three tasks. So the "solution" that I have come up with is

```
      const hasMaxDateTime =
        value &&
        isDefined(value.maxCreatedAt) &&
        isNaN(Date.parse(value.maxCreatedAt)) === false;
    . . . .
      let maxCreatedAt = yup
        .date()
        .default(undefined)
        .transform((curr, orig) => orig === '' ? null : curr)
        .typeError('Please enter a valid date');
    . . . .
      if (hasMaxDateTime) {
        minCreatedAt = minCreatedAt.concat(
          minCreatedAt.max(
            yup.ref('maxCreatedAt'),
            'Min created must be less than max created',
          ),
        );
      }
. . . .
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    type: yup.number().nullable(),
    statusCode: yup.string().nullable(),
    minCreatedAt,
    maxCreatedAt,
  });
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I validates that maxdate is not less than mindate just fine. But it doesn't seem to validate that there is an empty string or invalid date?

Answer (score 10):

empty string will break the next validations, the transform method verifies the value is Date or null.
you can also add more checks in the transform function body.

```
yup.date().nullable().default(undefined)
    .transform((curr, orig) => orig === '' ? null : curr)
    .typeError("Invalid Date")
    .required("Field is required");
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I have tried.